# Android app crashes when I call mAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged();

Tags: android

This is an app thats supposed to get the contacts from the phone and list the ones that have a phone number in a listview. 
But the app crashes when mAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged(); is called :/
please help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    static int num = 0;

    ListView lv;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdaper;
    ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        getContacts();

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mAdaper = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts);

        lv.setAdapter(mAdaper);

    }

    private void getContacts(){

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, // projection,
                null, // selection,
                null, // selectionArgs,
                "_ID DESC" // sortOrder
        );

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext() && num < 10) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer
                        .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                    // TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    String row = id + " - " + name;
                    contacts.add(row);
                    //mAdaper.add(row);
                    num++;

                }
            }
        }
        mAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling getContacts() before initializing the mAdapter. In the getContacts(), you are calling mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();. At this point, mAdapter is not yet initialized.

Call getContacts() after you have initialized the mAdapter.

```
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts);
lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
getContacts();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this (I think it's very dirty) by calling onCreate(null) after changing data-sets. This restores my Recycler perfectly:

This crashes:

```
    // delete selected items from database
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM country WHERE selected");
    cursor = getDBContent();
    cursor.close();
    mainActivityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This not:

```
    // delete selected items from database
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM country WHERE selected");
    cursor = getDBContent();
    cursor.close();
    this.onCreate(null);
```

I did a System.out.println() and wether the cursor nor the mainActivityAdapter has been "null". But in my example, the index of the cursor seems to be the couse of the crashing, even that I restored it. But I don't mind, as long as the above is working and running stable (maybe it is inefficient).